# Magento 2 URL migration problem

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, 404-page

I had a magento website `abc.com` and now migrated all files and database to `xyz.com`.
After changing database and url path, the `xyz.com` is displaying the same home page(front-page). But, when you click on any product or page in home page or go to Admin Login url:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /admin was not found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Need your help.

Comment: Which web service you use?  There is `.htaccess` file for Apache?

Comment: no .htaccess Sir

Comment: You should copy the `.htaccess` from your old site to the new site.

Comment: I did Sir but still  problem can't access dashboard cant accces any produict or page only front-page(hame page) is showing

Comment: Try to flush Magento cache and try again.

Comment: still no way Sir

Comment: you can check to go to any page or product and see

Comment: ou can check to go to any page or product and see 
go to [link] (http://emiratideal.com)

Comment: You can try to add `index.php` and access `http://emiratideal.com/index.php/antonia-racer-tank.html`. You can take a look: https://secure.nerdster.com.au/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=109

Comment: You also take a look here: https://community.magento.com/t5/Installing-Magento-2/Magento-2-Localhost-Admin-url-returning-404/td-p/42320

Comment: still Sir I tried to add them add but no way

Comment: How you added? You can update your question with what you tried.

Comment: You restarted your web service?

Comment: RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ http://www.emiratideal.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^www.emiratideal.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.emiratideal.com/$1 [R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*) $1 [R=301,QSA,L]

Comment: i am having the same issue. Have you found a solution? I copied my old .htaccess file to the new server, and still it doesnt work. Only the homepage loads.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like url_revrite module does not enable on the new server.

see more detail in http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/apache.html#enable-rewrites-and-htaccess-for-apache-24

Comment: url_revrite module is enabled by default from my hosting as I am using dedicated hosting

Answer (score 0):

**Option.1**

go to below configuration in admin

**Stores -> Configurations -> General ->Web  -> Search Engine Optimization -> Use Web Server Rewrites**

and **disable**  "Use Web Server Rewrites".

---

**Option.2**

run below command from ssh

```
php bin/magento config:set web/seo/use_rewrites 0 
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

---

if it works for you that mean php rewrite module is disabled on your server

hope this helps you :)